# if- else statement in one line code python; syntax error

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I just want to convert the number in text and if it is a text just return the word, but I get a syntax error after else. Is it possible to write the statement in one line?

```
text = [p.number_to_words(words) for words in text if words.isdigit() else words]
```

Comment: In the future when asking questions about errors, always please copy-paste the errors into the question, in full and complete, and as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move the `if ... else` before the `for ... in`:

```
text = [p.number_to_words(words) if words.isdigit() else words for words in text]
```